# Transfer session between 2 sites?

Tags: php, session

i have 2 website A.com and B.com. I wanna send my basket on A.com to B.com with PHP session.
for example:
my A.com basket;

```
session_start();
$i=0;
$_SESSION['basket'][$i]->name = "apple";
$_SESSION['basket'][$i]->description = "apppppppp";
//..etc
```

im trying to connect from B.com and i see noting from session. How can i see basket?

I have to see this

```
{
"loggedInUser": null,
"sessionid": "7hipbcrktd41lk82lvj8n967n0",
"products": [
{
"id": "8850",
"image": "737986198.jpg",
"title": "iPhone X Lansman Red Kılıf",
"code": "PY0088",
"category": "277",
"subcategory": "284",
"products": "284",
"marka": "APPLE",
"model": "iPhone X",
"type": "normal",
"price": "89.90",
"quantity": 1
}
]
}
```

but im see this

```
{"loggedInUser":null,"sessionid":"evlddomnf5tn116mu9aqasr2l1"}
```

even i set session_id still not working. please help.

Answer (score 0):

**It will helps you:**

1.If the session is set in a cookie, you can't transfer it (unless to a subdomain), make sure you transfer it via GET

2.In order to have the data associated with the SESSION sync accross the servers, you have to share the file system, at least for the path the SESSIONS are saved (e.g. /tmp/php)

3.if you save objects in the SESSION make sure they are available on both servers

**Cross-domain session ids**

Session ids are passed around using cookies by default. Since your websites are on different domains the session cookie does not transfer over, so that's one thing that prevents cross-domain sessions from working.

One technique to have the session ids transfer over is to append them to the query string of all your requests (PHP even has some degree of built-in support for this). However, this way of doing things has many drawbacks -- the most important being that people copy/paste URLs all the time, with all that implies about revealing valid and reusing invalid session ids -- and therefore is not recommended.

A much better approach would be to use Javascript to make cross-domain requests across all of the interested domains (which would need to be cooperating in this of course). This way you can seamlessly transfer your session id across as many servers as you need to.

A simple solution to this problem would be to use a ***custom session handler*** that stores the data on a database or other globally accessible store.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.customhandler.php